# How can I decrypt Blowfish ciphertext with a salted header?

Tags: perl, cryptography, openssl, blowfish

I have some ciphertext that has been encrypted using Perl's [Crypt::CBC](http://search.cpan.org/~lds/Crypt-CBC-2.30/CBC.pm) module that I wish to decrypt elsewhere.

The ciphertext was generated using the 'simple' version of the `Crypt::CBC` constructor, that is:

```
use Crypt::CBC;
$cipher = Crypt::CBC->new( -key    => 'my secret key',
                           -cipher => 'Blowfish'
                          );
```

From reading the MAN page, this method of construction will take the simple string key and random salt to generate an IV & literal key to use for encryption, as well as embed a header with the salt.

> "salt" -- Combine the passphrase with
>   an 8-byte random value to
>              generate both the block cipher key and the IV from the
>              provided passphrase. The salt will be appended to the
>              beginning of the data stream allowing decryption to
>              regenerate both the key and IV given the correct passphrase.
>              This method is compatible with current versions of OpenSSL.

I now need to decrypt the ciphertext on another platform that only supports CBC decryption given the ciphertext, a literal key & IV.  To attempt to generate the literal key, IV & salt, I used Crypt::CBC to generate the values like so:

```
my $crypt = new Crypt::CBC(-key => 'my secret key', -cipher => 'Blowfish');
my $out = $crypt->decrypt($ciphertext);
my $literal_key = $crypt->key();
my $iv = $crypt->iv();
my $salt = $crypt->salt();
```

The decryption here is correct, but I've been unable to use the generated literal key & IV to decrypt the cipher; this produces rubbish:

```
my $crypt2 = new Crypt::CBC(
    -literal_key => 1,
    -key => $literal_key,
    -cipher => 'Blowfish',
    -iv => $iv,
    -header => 'none');
my $rubbish - $crypt2->decrypt($ciphertext);
```

I can't provide a literal key and use a salted header so I'm lost as to the next move.

How can I decrypt this text?

**EDIT**: The target system is not running Perl, but I have been able to generate the identical value as in $rubbish above, so I'm sure it's using the same algorithm (CBC, Blowfish) to decipher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To decrypt the stream, you first need to remove the header added by Crypt::CBC's "salt" mode. The header consists of the 8 characters `Salted__` followed by 8 bytes of salt data.

In perl, something like this should do it:

```
my $crypt2 = new Crypt::CBC(
    -literal_key => 1,
    -key => $literal_key,
    -cipher => 'Blowfish',
    -iv => $iv,
    -header => 'none');
my $cleartext = $crypt2->decrypt(substr($ciphertext, 16));
```

Comment: As an extra note in case another searcher is ever in the same boat, I had several discrete texts to decipher, all encrypted with the same passphrase so had to calculate the IV & key from the salt.  I ported the code straight out of the [_salted_key_and_iv function in Crypt::CBC](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/LDS/Crypt-CBC-2.30/CBC.pm).

Answer (score 1):

This may work.  Your key will have to be exactly 56 bytes in length and the iv will have to be exactly eight bytes long:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Crypt::CBC;

my $key = "x" x 56;
my $iv  = "x" x 8;

my $plaintext  = "this is just some normal text\n";
my $ciphertext = Crypt::CBC->new(
    -cipher      => 'Blowfish',
    -header      => 'none',
    -literal_key => 1,
    -key         => $key,
    -iv          => $iv,
)->encrypt($plaintext);

print Crypt::CBC->new(
    -cipher      => 'Blowfish',
    -header      => 'none',
    -literal_key => 1,
    -key         => $key,
    -iv          => $iv,
)->decrypt($ciphertext);
```

Comment: I've got Blowfish libraries on both systems, but the trouble system is an embedded Windows application that cannot run Perl.  I have managed to get both systems outputting the identical rubbish-text produced by my last Perl example, so the Blowfish part appears to be working.  I don't have code on the target system that supports IV & key generation from a passphrase, or the embedded salt & header.

Comment: Are you certain the Windows application is using a CBC?  You might try just using `Crypt::Blowfish` directly.

Comment: yes - for 2 reasions. 1) the function is called blf_BytesDecRawCBC and 2) when called, it generates the *exact* same output as the final example I gave in the OP (the 'rubbish' output).

Answer (score 1):

If anybody needs the _salted_key_and_iv function in PHP - here it is:

```
function _salted_key_and_iv ($pass, $salt) {
        if(strlen($salt) != 8) {
            die("Salt must be 8 bytes long");
        }

        $key_len = 56;
        $iv_len  = 8;

        $desired_len = $key_len+$iv_len;

        $data  = '';
        $d = '';

        while (strlen($data) < $desired_len) {
            $d = pack("H*", md5($d . $pass . $salt));
            $data .= "$d";
        }

        return $data;
}
```